# So is the password, "this is my password" a safe password?

Tags: security, passwords

I just saw [this](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/password_strength.png) xkcd comic about how a longer password is more secure than a shorter password due to entropy.

My question is, why aren't more people encouraged to use passwords like this? why are password requirements often, "at least 8 characters" only? When you use a password generate in a web app it often gives you 8-10 alpha-numeric characters, and marks it as "very strong". Why doesn't it give you a password like "this cheese tastes great"?

Or do attackers use dictionary attacks often, which would easily reveal such passwords?

Shouldn't we be encouraging users to start using passwords like "my password is M4nch3ster34!" or "I dont like ch33sec4k3sss" so it has the non-dictionary word, but also a length good enough to stop brute force?

Comment: English phrases are getting pretty iffy. Really the best you can do is giant random strings stored with a password manager (but even that has problems being a single point of failure).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about password security, not programming. It might be appropriate on http://security.stackexchange.com/, but it's very likely to be a duplicate; check before posting there.

Comment: Forcing a password to have at least one uppercase and one numeric is less secure than allowing any password (such as a phrase) because it reduces the possible options by millions. Apple is the worst offender for this - they even store your previous passwords to prevent you from reusing them. "Enter a memorable password" umm... you won't actually let me.

Comment: Sequences of randomly selected words ("scholar curvier corrode iceberg") are much more secure than meaningful sentences ("this is my password").

Comment: Replacing those letters with those numbers is pointless. If you wanted to brute force your way in somewhere, isn't that the first thing you'd  try...?

Comment: @Popnoodles my thinking was that, if they have a list of dictionary words, they might try them randomly with spaces, so "my password is manchester" would contain 4 dictionary words, but "M4nch3ster34!" on it's own probably isn't in a list of words. this string alone could probably be easily discovered by brute force, but *only* if they know "my passsword is" comes first.

Comment: @Popnoodles: I don't know what Apple does, but they don't necessarily store passwords in clear text. They could just store the hashes of your last few passwords, and compare the hash of your new password against the stored ones.

Comment: I didn't ever think they did store them plain text.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is: no, that is not a safe password, at least in the sense of the comic strip's analysis. Because the phrase is grammatically correct (unlike the example on xkcd), there are many fewer entropy bits than you would think.

However, sentences that only you can remember can be very effective passwords (I think this was your broader point), and the main reason why they are not more commonly used is, IMHO, purely cultural/historic, having to do with 8 character limits, character code pages, and other relics of another time in computing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Theory says that will be easy to find, practices says the opposite. To find something like that, one needs a customized set of rules to make the guessing. The rule should be: given a set of words, concatenate each words to form a 4 words sentence, as many times as it is needed form the original set.

So theory says it is easy to find, practice says nobody will have that rule unless they know something about you/the context to put it in their john.conf (or any other vocabulary bruteforce tool config).

I cracked a lot of passwords for work, never targeting a specific user, but always trying to obtain any valid credential to start of something (DB, ssh, win, etc...). Length is usually enough against that threat (someone who randomly wants to access something and searches any good password).

When it comes to personalized/targeted attacks, one could know more about the victim and apply more refined rules. Look at CRUNCH, it is way too easy to expand a wordlist with it http://pentestlab.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/creating-wordlists-with-crunch/ and this is the kind of things people do when targeting a victim.